# Anyway to speed up this function?

Tags: c#, xna

I have a voxel (minecraft style) engine in XNA, the world is divided into chunks and when a cube is modified I recreate the vertex buffer by scanning through all the cubes and checking if the faces are visible.  This normally works at an nice speed but when the cubes are arranged in certain ways (such that the vertex buffer will be a lot bigger) it can take over a frame to generate the new chunk.  In the worst possible configuration (with the most possible vertices showing) it can take up to 100ms.  The following part of the code represents about 80-90ms of the 100, and it's ran 131,072 times when the chunk updates, on the worst possible configuration it creates 32,768 cubes and on all the other runs it creates 0 vertices.

I'm on an i5 2500k as well so this might be really bad on older systems.

I can't think of anyway to improve the speed and I'm pretty new to programming so I thought I would post it here for some advice?  Thanks.

```
public void GenerateCubeGeometryAtPosition(int x, int y, int z, byte id)
{
    //We check if there's a cube in the six directions around the cube
    //if there's no cube ot the cube is transparent we add the vertices to the vertex list
    //if the cube is on the outside of the chunk we check the cube in the chunk next to it assuming it's loaded

    //if we have to build part of the cube we make a new vertex
    //first 3 bytes in the vertex are the position relative to the chunk
    //4th byte is for normals, we check it in the shader to figure out the normal
    //the next 2 bytes in the properties are for the texture positons on the texture atlas
    //last 2 bytes are for other properties of the vertex like light/shade etc

    //Check up and down
    if (y > YSize - 2)
    {
        ChunkVertices.Add(new VertexPositionNormalSmall(new Byte4(x, y + 1, z, 0f), GlobalWorld.Blocks[id].VertexPropertiesTop[0]));
        ChunkVertices.Add(new VertexPositionNormalSmall(new Byte4(1 + x, y + 1, z, 0f), GlobalWorld.Blocks[id].VertexPropertiesTop[1]));
        ChunkVertices.Add(new VertexPositionNormalSmall(new Byte4(x, y + 1, 1 + z, 0f), GlobalWorld.Blocks[id].VertexPropertiesTop[2]));
        ChunkVertices.Add(new VertexPositionNormalSmall(new Byte4(1 + x, y + 1, 1 + z, 0f), GlobalWorld.Blocks[id].VertexPropertiesTop[3]));
    }
    else if (Blocks[x, y + 1, z] == 0 || GlobalWorld.Blocks[Blocks[x, y + 1, z]].Transparent)
    {
        ChunkVertices.Add(new VertexPositionNormalSmall(new Byte4(x, y + 1, z, 0f), GlobalWorld.Blocks[id].VertexPropertiesTop[0]));
        ChunkVertices.Add(new VertexPositionNormalSmall(new Byte4(1 + x, y + 1, z, 0f), GlobalWorld.Blocks[id].VertexPropertiesTop[1]));
        ChunkVertices.Add(new VertexPositionNormalSmall(new Byte4(x, y + 1, 1 + z, 0f), GlobalWorld.Blocks[id].VertexPropertiesTop[2]));
        ChunkVertices.Add(new VertexPositionNormalSmall(new Byte4(1 + x, y + 1, 1 + z, 0f), GlobalWorld.Blocks[id].VertexPropertiesTop[3]));

    }
    if (y != 0 && (Blocks[x, y - 1, z] == 0 || GlobalWorld.Blocks[Blocks[x, y - 1, z]].Transparent))
    {
        ChunkVertices.Add(new VertexPositionNormalSmall(new Byte4(x, y, z, 1f), GlobalWorld.Blocks[id].VertexPropertiesBottom[0]));
        ChunkVertices.Add(new VertexPositionNormalSmall(new Byte4(x, y, 1 + z, 1f), GlobalWorld.Blocks[id].VertexPropertiesBottom[1]));
        ChunkVertices.Add(new VertexPositionNormalSmall(new Byte4(1 + x, y, z, 1f), GlobalWorld.Blocks[id].VertexPropertiesBottom[2]));
        ChunkVertices.Add(new VertexPositionNormalSmall(new Byte4(1 + x, y, 1 + z, 1f), GlobalWorld.Blocks[id].VertexPropertiesBottom[3]));
    }

    //check Right and Left of the cube and the adjacent chunk at the edges
    if (x == 0)
    {
        if (this.RightChunk != -1 && (GlobalWorld.LoadedChunks[this.RightChunk].Blocks[XSize - 1, y, z] == 0 || GlobalWorld.Blocks[GlobalWorld.LoadedChunks[this.RightChunk].Blocks[XSize - 1, y, z]].Transparent))
        {
            ChunkVertices.Add(new VertexPositionNormalSmall(new Byte4(x, y, z, 3f), GlobalWorld.Blocks[id].VertexPropertiesRight[0]));
            ChunkVertices.Add(new VertexPositionNormalSmall(new Byte4(x, y + 1, z, 3f), GlobalWorld.Blocks[id].VertexPropertiesRight[1]));
            ChunkVertices.Add(new VertexPositionNormalSmall(new Byte4(x, y, 1 + z, 3f), GlobalWorld.Blocks[id].VertexPropertiesRight[2]));
            ChunkVertices.Add(new VertexPositionNormalSmall(new Byte4(x, y + 1, 1 + z, 3f), GlobalWorld.Blocks[id].VertexPropertiesRight[3]));
        }
    }
    else if (Blocks[x - 1, y, z] == 0 || GlobalWorld.Blocks[Blocks[x - 1, y, z]].Transparent)
    {
        //right
        ChunkVertices.Add(new VertexPositionNormalSmall(new Byte4(x, y, z, 3f), GlobalWorld.Blocks[id].VertexPropertiesRight[0]));
        ChunkVertices.Add(new VertexPositionNormalSmall(new Byte4(x, y + 1, z, 3f), GlobalWorld.Blocks[id].VertexPropertiesRight[1]));
        ChunkVertices.Add(new VertexPositionNormalSmall(new Byte4(x, y, 1 + z, 3f), GlobalWorld.Blocks[id].VertexPropertiesRight[2]));
        ChunkVertices.Add(new VertexPositionNormalSmall(new Byte4(x, y + 1, 1 + z, 3f), GlobalWorld.Blocks[id].VertexPropertiesRight[3]));
    }
    if (x > XSize - 2)
    {
        if (this.LeftChunk != -1 && (GlobalWorld.LoadedChunks[this.LeftChunk].Blocks[0, y, z] == 0 || GlobalWorld.Blocks[GlobalWorld.LoadedChunks[this.LeftChunk].Blocks[0, y, z]].Transparent))
        {
            ChunkVertices.Add(new VertexPositionNormalSmall(new Byte4(1 + x, y, z, 2f), GlobalWorld.Blocks[id].VertexPropertiesLeft[0]));
            ChunkVertices.Add(new VertexPositionNormalSmall(new Byte4(1 + x, y, 1 + z, 2f), GlobalWorld.Blocks[id].VertexPropertiesLeft[1]));
            ChunkVertices.Add(new VertexPositionNormalSmall(new Byte4(1 + x, 1 + y, z, 2f), GlobalWorld.Blocks[id].VertexPropertiesLeft[2]));
            ChunkVertices.Add(new VertexPositionNormalSmall(new Byte4(1 + x, 1 + y, 1 + z, 2f), GlobalWorld.Blocks[id].VertexPropertiesLeft[3]));
        }
    }
    else if (Blocks[x + 1, y, z] == 0 || GlobalWorld.Blocks[Blocks[x + 1, y, z]].Transparent)
    {
        //left
        ChunkVertices.Add(new VertexPositionNormalSmall(new Byte4(1 + x, y, z, 2f), GlobalWorld.Blocks[id].VertexPropertiesLeft[0]));
        ChunkVertices.Add(new VertexPositionNormalSmall(new Byte4(1 + x, y, 1 + z, 2f), GlobalWorld.Blocks[id].VertexPropertiesLeft[1]));
        ChunkVertices.Add(new VertexPositionNormalSmall(new Byte4(1 + x, 1 + y, z, 2f), GlobalWorld.Blocks[id].VertexPropertiesLeft[2]));
        ChunkVertices.Add(new VertexPositionNormalSmall(new Byte4(1 + x, 1 + y, 1 + z, 2f), GlobalWorld.Blocks[id].VertexPropertiesLeft[3]));
    }

    //check Back and Front of the cube and the adjacent chunk at the edges
    if (z == 0)
    {
        if (this.BackChunk != -1 && (GlobalWorld.LoadedChunks[this.BackChunk].Blocks[x, y, ZSize - 1] == 0 || GlobalWorld.Blocks[GlobalWorld.LoadedChunks[this.BackChunk].Blocks[x, y, ZSize - 1]].Transparent))
        {
            ChunkVertices.Add(new VertexPositionNormalSmall(new Byte4(x, y, z, 5f), GlobalWorld.Blocks[id].VertexPropertiesBack[0]));
            ChunkVertices.Add(new VertexPositionNormalSmall(new Byte4(1 + x, y, z, 5f), GlobalWorld.Blocks[id].VertexPropertiesBack[1]));
            ChunkVertices.Add(new VertexPositionNormalSmall(new Byte4(x, y + 1, z, 5f), GlobalWorld.Blocks[id].VertexPropertiesBack[2]));
            ChunkVertices.Add(new VertexPositionNormalSmall(new Byte4(1 + x, y + 1, z, 5f), GlobalWorld.Blocks[id].VertexPropertiesBack[3]));
        }
    }
    else if (Blocks[x, y, z - 1] == 0 || GlobalWorld.Blocks[Blocks[x, y, z - 1]].Transparent)
    {
        ChunkVertices.Add(new VertexPositionNormalSmall(new Byte4(x, y, z, 5f), GlobalWorld.Blocks[id].VertexPropertiesBack[0]));
        ChunkVertices.Add(new VertexPositionNormalSmall(new Byte4(1 + x, y, z, 5f), GlobalWorld.Blocks[id].VertexPropertiesBack[1]));
        ChunkVertices.Add(new VertexPositionNormalSmall(new Byte4(x, y + 1, z, 5f), GlobalWorld.Blocks[id].VertexPropertiesBack[2]));
        ChunkVertices.Add(new VertexPositionNormalSmall(new Byte4(1 + x, y + 1, z, 5f), GlobalWorld.Blocks[id].VertexPropertiesBack[3]));
    }
    if (z > ZSize - 2)
    {
        if (this.ForwardChunk != -1 && (GlobalWorld.LoadedChunks[this.ForwardChunk].Blocks[x, y, 0] == 0 || GlobalWorld.Blocks[GlobalWorld.LoadedChunks[this.ForwardChunk].Blocks[x, y, 0]].Transparent))
        {
            ChunkVertices.Add(new VertexPositionNormalSmall(new Byte4(x, y, 1 + z, 4f), GlobalWorld.Blocks[id].VertexPropertiesFront[0]));
            ChunkVertices.Add(new VertexPositionNormalSmall(new Byte4(x, y + 1, 1 + z, 4f), GlobalWorld.Blocks[id].VertexPropertiesFront[1]));
            ChunkVertices.Add(new VertexPositionNormalSmall(new Byte4(1 + x, y, 1 + z, 4f), GlobalWorld.Blocks[id].VertexPropertiesFront[2]));
            ChunkVertices.Add(new VertexPositionNormalSmall(new Byte4(1 + x, y + 1, 1 + z, 4f), GlobalWorld.Blocks[id].VertexPropertiesFront[3]));
        }
    }
    else if (Blocks[x, y, z + 1] == 0 || GlobalWorld.Blocks[Blocks[x, y, z + 1]].Transparent)
    {
        ChunkVertices.Add(new VertexPositionNormalSmall(new Byte4(x, y, 1 + z, 4f), GlobalWorld.Blocks[id].VertexPropertiesFront[0]));
        ChunkVertices.Add(new VertexPositionNormalSmall(new Byte4(x, y + 1, 1 + z, 4f), GlobalWorld.Blocks[id].VertexPropertiesFront[1]));
        ChunkVertices.Add(new VertexPositionNormalSmall(new Byte4(1 + x, y, 1 + z, 4f), GlobalWorld.Blocks[id].VertexPropertiesFront[2]));
        ChunkVertices.Add(new VertexPositionNormalSmall(new Byte4(1 + x, y + 1, 1 + z, 4f), GlobalWorld.Blocks[id].VertexPropertiesFront[3]));
    }
}
```

Comment: For a start you could get GlobalWorld.Blocks[id] once and store it in a local variable (unless GlobalWorld.Blocks[id] returns a different value each time it's called). Apply same philosophy to any other class property you're repeatedly accessing. Also, this is very specific so not really SO-appropriate. Try http://gamedev.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Why is your `Byte4` using floats?

Comment: Because I changed it from Vector4 and forgot to change them, thanks for reminding me about that.  Why does getting the vars from GlobalWorld.Blocks[id] cause a slow down?  Wouldn't it be the same speed?

Comment: @Levi it needs to re-evaluate the Blocks getter on GlobalWorld, and also re-retrieve the "id" element of Blocks.  Better to just do it once and reuse the value.

Comment: Thanks but that had no noticeable effect.  I think I'll have to decrease the chunk size and sacrifice a higher fps.

Comment: Seems dumb, but pre-computing the various "`+1`"s might help.  And pull out your (potentially) redundant `GlobalWorld.Blocks` lookups.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any obvious reason for slowness in this code. If small code changes don't seem to give you the necessary speedup, I would try a different implementation.

If I understood correctly, you reconstruct the vertex buffer for the whole chunk of 64x64x32 (= 131072) blocks when one block changes. Assuming that the blocks in a chunk change only a few at a time, it might be much faster to have one persistent vertex buffer that contained all the sides of all cubes at predetermined places. When the status of one cube face changes, you only need to change four values in the vertex buffer instead of creating the whole vertex buffer from scratch.

For example, you could have the four vertices of the top face of the cube at (5, 6, 7) at four consecutive vertex buffer indices starting from `GetCubeFaceStartIndex(5, 6, 7, CubeFaceType.Top)`.

```
enum CubeFaceType { Top, Bottom, Left, Right, Front, Back }

int GetCubeFaceStartIndex(int x, int y, int z, CubeFaceType face)
{
    return 4 * ((int)cubeFace + 6 * (x + CHUNK_WIDTH * (y + CHUNK_HEIGHT * z));
}
```

To remove one face (when the block is deleted), you would set the four vertices to the same value, e.g. `new VertexPositionNormalSmall(Vector4.Zero, DummyProperties)`. Note that a triangle whose vertices share the same position is not visible on screen.

If you need to add a face or change its properties, you would do what you did before, only directly at the indices determined by the location of the cube and the face.

This implementation of course requires a larger vertex buffer. If your chunks are 64x64x32 cubes in size, the vertex buffer would need to be 64*64*64*6*4 = 3145728 vertices long, which may not be practical. Reducing the size of chunks may be necessary.

Answer (score 1):

1. What is the Hidden Vertex // Shown Vertex ratio, in a 'typical' configuration ? Because, since graphic cards will not show the hidden vertex anyway, it may takes more time to remove edges than just throw them at the graphic card.
2. In the same kind of idea, maybe it might be interesting to only handle at a cube level : if a cube is fully within other cubes, don't add the vertex, if not add all the cube vertices with no check. It depends here of the Hidden / Shown vertex ratio.
3. I guess that you noticed that if a Cube is deeply hidden, i mean by that : surrounded by hidden cubes only, it will be shown by your algorithm. But to take advantage of that i only see a complicated algorithm like 3D paint... mmm....
4. If you know each change that occurs (only ONE block gets on or Off) you might greatly speed up things by only updating a part of the vertex list instead of building all each time.
   If One block gets ON, notice that building all again is not mandatory : just add the vertex of the new cube, and the display will be ok. But the vertex list will contain non-displayed vertex you might want to clear at some time... :-)
   If one block gets OFF, it will show some of the surrounding cube's vertex, but in a limited aerea around the hidden block only. 
   So a little bit like vvnurmi suggest, it would be handy to have a (Cube side) --> (Vertex start and end index) dictionnary. So you can erase a given cube.